# Firebase Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My App doesn't work offline. I am getting this error:

```
myRef = No such instance field: 'myRef'
myValueEventListener = No such instance field: 'myValueEventListener'
```

Even if I already set:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Code:

```
  database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            myRef = database.getReference("lifts");
            myRef.keepSynced(true);
            myValueEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        lift = item.getValue(Lift.class);
                        lift.key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        arrayLifts.add(lift);

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

#askFirebase
```

Comment: Try Restarting your android studio and also go to file>invalidate caches/restart.

Comment: `myChildEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` why have you mentioned **ChildEventListener** and used **ValueEventListener** ? Can you please share how you are defining these member variables ?

Comment: Sry I updated my code.

Comment: Are you still facing same issue even after restarting studio and invalidating caches ?

Comment: Yes when I am connect to the Internet it works but when I am offline it won 't work.

Comment: Please can you share java code of full activity as well ?

Comment: Can you share your full java code of activity ?